# JAR executable pros and cons

Tags: java, jar, portability

I have been using JAR files to export my projects in my Java subject at school. I noticed it's portability (assuming the computer in use has Java installed). However, with that fact, why haven't I seen developers distribute Java programs using a JAR file? What are the pros (besides portability) and cons (aside from using C++) of using the JAR executable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm hoping that the advantages are pretty obvious.  The biggest disadvantage I've run into is when there are additional dependencies that are required that aren't included in the JAR.  A MANIFEST can be included to set the classpath - but this requires that all of the dependencies exist with pre-defined names in a pre-defined location.  This can be worked-around with a loader script (to set the classpath, etc.) - at which point not everything is contained in the single JAR anymore, and most of the advantages are lost.

Comment: i suppose the disadvantages will then overrun and outweigh the advantages after that.

Comment: You can also embed the dependencies and resources into a single double-clickable .jar as a build step.

Comment: I haven't seen a case where the manifest file doesn't work. Just use a relative path such as lib/example.jar instead of an absolute path. Then the lib dir containing all the library jar files get placed in the same location as the main jar.

Comment: Sarel - true, for most cases.  I just had some cases where I had several JARs packaged like this, and wanted them to share many of the same libraries to reduce the required footprint.  This is easy to do with symbolic links on Linux, but becomes more difficult on other OS's.

Comment: You can work around this problem by putting all the classes in a single jar. You can do this using the unzip and jar ant tasks or you can use a program like yguard to take care of it for you. With yguard it also shrinks the size of your JAR by only including code you're using and it can also obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 5):

There are two components to the question. The first is shipping a JAR and using no installer. The second component to the question is the pros and cons of a using just a JAR on the machine once the executable has been deployed. I'm starting to suspect that the OP was asking about the first component. My answer tries to answer the second component.

Pros

1. Less work. Don't have to make an executable for each platform you want to support.

Cons

1. If the user doesn't have java installed it can't tell the user why it can't run. An exe can also download java for the user.
2. If your app requires a specific version of Java it may run with the wrong version. A a native executable can locate the correct one and use it. This point isn't as important as it used to be since Java 6 has been around so long.
3. Can't have an customized icon for the executable on Windows.
4. You can't control startup options such as the maximum memory that your app can use. For most apps this is ok but sometimes you need more memory.
5. A JAR cant be used for a Windows service. There must be an exe wrapper around it (jsmooth has this).

Another alternative to producing an executable is to use JNLP. A web page can check for java before it forwards the user to the .jnlp file.